# moderncv extend hrule

Tags: moderncv, cv

In the following example, my rule does not extend to cover my entire text. Is there a quick post-package addition to ensure that the section rule extends to the end of the margin on the right hand size.

```
% ============================================
% document setup
% ============================================
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% --------------------------------------------
% header style
% --------------------------------------------
\moderncvstyle{classic}
% style options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% --------------------------------------------
% header details
% --------------------------------------------
\usepackage{import}
\name{John}{Smith}
\address{1234 Main Street}{Chicago, IL}{12345}
\phone[fixed]{+1 (123) 456-7899}
\homepage{https://github.com/john-smith}

% ============================================
% CV content
% ============================================

% --------------------------------------------
% body style
% --------------------------------------------
\moderncvstyle{banking}
% style options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'

% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% begin
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% --------------------------------------------
\section{Experience}
% --------------------------------------------
\begin{itemize}
\item[]{
\cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}}

\item[]{
\cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}}
\end{itemize}

% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% end
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, how might I cleanly edit a single line in the `moderncvbodyi.sty` source to adjust the `\hrule`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style `banking` of class `moderncv` has a special layout, that is based on the  usage of command `\cventry` **without** beeing inserted in an `itemize` environment.

Therefore it is defined in this way:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\maincolumnwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% <============
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}% <====================================
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Inserted in an environment `itemize` the length `\maincolumnwidth` calculated earlier is too long.

You can omit using environment `itemize` or have to define an own command `\mycventry` (I changed `\maincolumnwidth` to `\linewidth`):

```
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% <=============
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <=====================================
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

With the following MWE (first I used your way, second I used the usual way to use `\cventry` and then `\mycventry`):

```
% ============================================
% document setup
% ============================================
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\moderncvstyle{banking}
% style options: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% <=============
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <===========================
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

% --------------------------------------------
% header details
% --------------------------------------------
\usepackage{import}
\name{John}{Smith}
\address{1234 Main Street}{Chicago, IL}{12345}
\phone[fixed]{+1 (123) 456-7899}
\homepage{https://github.com/john-smith}

% ============================================
% CV content
% ============================================


% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% begin
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

% --------------------------------------------
\section{Experience}
% --------------------------------------------
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
  \cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
  {Employee} % role
  {Company} % company
  {City, State} % city
  {important} % role title
  {\begin{itemize}% main text
     \item abcdefg
     \item abcdefg
     \item abcdefg
   \end{itemize}}

\item[]
\mycventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}
\end{itemize}

\section{Experience}
\cventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}

\mycventry{June 2017 -- September 2017} % date
{Employee} % role
{Company} % company
{City, State} % city
{important} % role title
{\begin{itemize}% main text
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\item abcdefg
\end{itemize}}

% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
% end
% ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: THANK YOU! very helpful to see the bigger picture of what's going on w.r.t. the environment

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to the accepted great answer, I also used the following to ensure that line spill-over for items within `\mycvenrty` would end appropriately:

```
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}% <============= (original edit)
    {\bfseries #4} & {\bfseries #5}\\%
    {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}} & {\itshape #2}\\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}% <============= (new edit)
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```