# New command definition - help with understanding

Tags: tables, macros

I'm trying to understand use the below user defined command. Could someone help me understand how the command works? In particular, I am a bit confused on what the `[0.25em]` does here, what `{@{}l}` and `{l@{}}` mean. The latter 2 seems like some kind of alignment but I couldn't seem to find definitive information on this.

Also, what does the `if else` statement at the end do?

```
\newcommand*{\customcventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\bfseries #4}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\bfseries #5}
  \end{tabular} \\
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l} 
    {\itshape #3}
  \end{tabular}
  \hfill% move it to the right
  \begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     {\itshape #2}
  \end{tabular}
  \ifx&#7&%
  \else{\\%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}%
      \small#7%
    \end{minipage}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}
```

Here's an example of its usage (actually, I've changed this since I downloaded template, so I'm not sure if this is the original intended usage):

```
{\customcventry{Adviser:}{Degree Name}{University of Blah}{Expected Graduate date}{}{Concentration: }}
```

and the corresponding output
[image]

Comment: Welcome! `[.25em]` means that the command has an optional argument with default value `.25em`. That is, by default you will have `\addvspace{.25em}` but if you call `\customcventry[.1em]` that distance will change to `.1em`, say.  `{@{}l}` means (basically) "left-aligned column with tight space on the left", and likewise for `{l@{}}`. (I am not sure I like this command because it introduces stray spaces and so on, but this is just an opinion.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where does this command come from? It might be useful to provide some context.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks! Since there are 7 arguments, which argument is the optional one? I assume it's the last one?

Comment: @Vincent It's a CV template that I found on Overleaf. I will see if I can find the template again. One moment.

Comment: Nope, it is `#1`, which you pass to the command in square brackets, or just not pass it.

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, I can't seem to find the original template file anymore.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Ah okay. Do you know what the `if` statement is doing? I don't know what the condition `x&#7&%` means.

Comment: Would you by any chance have an example of how `\customcventry` is used? It's much easier to go through the elements of this macro if one can refer to an example of what, say, `#3` could be.

Comment: The definition seems to come from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398384/194703), where you can find an example of how it is used.

Comment: `\customcventry` is very similar to `\mycv` but not identical. BTW, `\ifx&#7&%` tests whether #7 is empty. When `#7` is empty, `\ifx` sees two `&`, which are equal, so the test is true (and nothing is done). If the test fails, a `minipage` with `#7` in it will be created.  The bottomline is that this is yet another way to customize an entry in the `moderncv` class, hence the name `\customcventry`.

Comment: @Mico Yes. I just edited that into the OP.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Just to confirm, with my usage `{\customcventry{Adviser:}{Degree Name}{University of Blah}{Expected Graduate date}{}{Concentration: }}
`, the `Adviser:` argument is the second argument? The first argument, if I choose to use it, has square brackets, `[]`? So for example, I could do `{\customcventry[0.1em]{Adviser:}{Degree Name}{University of Blah}{Expected Graduate date}{}{Concentration: }}`?

Comment: Sorry, this is not how this site works. You post some fragments here, ask for explanations, and users like @Mico and myself stop by and give feedback. Then you just modify the question without ever bothering to provide a complete example and/or a self-contained question. Why do we have to find out all these things if you already have a document in which you use the macro? Please post a minimal working example and a self-contained question.