# CV-entry dates overflowing and ghost comma added

Tags: vertical-alignment, moderncv

I am rather new to Latex and I am using it to build my Resume. I encountered two problems: the first one concerns the dates that overflow in the margins, while the second one is I think an embedded comma after the Master that I don't know how to remove. Do you have any idea how can I fix these two problems?
Code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.94]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
% personal data
\name{John Doe}{}
\phone[mobile]{123456789}                   
\email{whatever@gmail.com}                               

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}

\vspace{0pt}

\begin{itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{3pt}

\item{\cventry{}{Master in Whatever}{Random University | \normalfont Random place}{\normalfont 09/2021 - 03/2023}{\textit{}}{}}
\textbf{Coursework:} Random Courses
 
\vspace{4pt}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the alignment issue is simply caused by your using `itemize` on a `cventry`. The `itemize` environment indents all of its entries, shifting everything to the right. It is also not needed for a `\cventry` as they are already opitmized for the respective layouts you choose.

Comment: And the comma disappears, if you use the proper `{}`s of the `\cventry`, like so: `\cventry{}{Master in Whatever}{Random University | \normalfont Random place}{\normalfont 09/2021 - 03/2023}{}{\textbf{Coursework:} Random Courses}` In your case the `\textit{}` command causes the comma, because the `{}` is not empty and non-empty braces are treated as text, hence the comma.

Comment: For the part using `itemize` please see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392894/16550

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I should combine all of the comments to a proper answer. So here is my approach to your issue. Do note a few things: 1) `itemize` causes an indent, so be careful when using it whereever alignment is an issue. 2) Using `scale` as option to `geometry` is something I do not recommend, I'd rather use actual `margin`s. 3) If you want to add your courses as a list, you can use `minipage`s to do this, I added a small example. Remember to leave the empy line though, otherwise the next entry will be messed up.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        
% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{import}
% personal data
\name{John Doe}{}
\phone[mobile]{123456789}                   
\email{whatever@gmail.com}                               

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
        \cventry{}{Master in Whatever}{Random University | \normalfont Random place}{\normalfont 09/2021 - 03/2023}{}{\textbf{Coursework:} Random Courses}
        \cventry{}{Master in Whatever}{Random University | \normalfont Random place}{\normalfont 09/2021 - 03/2023}{}{}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
            \textbf{\small Coursework:} 
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{8cm}
            \begin{itemize}\small
                \item Random courses
                \item More courses
            \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}% leave one line empty after this command
    
        \cventry{}{Master in Whatever}{Random University | \normalfont Random place}{\normalfont 09/2021 - 03/2023}{}{\textbf{Coursework:} Random Courses}
\end{document}
```